# To detect the paste event in addressbar in gwt

Tags: java, url, gwt, address-bar

How to detect that pasting event is fired in the address bar through GWT? When we paste the thing from textbox to the addressbar then how to detect that pasting event in gwt.

Comment: Do you mean the browser address bar? Isnt that overly ambitious? Unless the browser gives you that info i dont think u can get it. what do u really want to do? something before user leaves current page?

Comment: What address bar are you talking about? Not clear...

Comment: as i am having some tinyurl in the label form and then pasting is in the addressbar and that redirect to the url

Answer (score 0):

What if a user decides to type an address instead of pasting it?

A standard approach is to use OnValueChangeEvent on a Textbox. It fires when a Textbox loses focus AND a value in the Textbox has changed, or when the Enter button is pressed while focus is still on the Textbox.

An alternative approach is to add a button, like "Take me there", that a user can press after a user is done entering the URL (either by pasting it or typing it).

Comment: are u trying to say that through onvaluechangeevent if we paste the url in the address bar then it will redirect to that url

Comment: i would like to give example for my question.as we are having that http://tinyurl.com/ they provide the small link to the whole url and if we paste that url in the address bar then that url will redirect to that main url only